# Moodle can't detect my php version

Tags: php, moodle

i've installed moodle from github. I'm using php5, then i can't install it.
So, i'm upgrade my php to php7.1, but still error. The error message like this : *Moodle 3.4 or later requires at least PHP 7.0.0 (currently using version 5.6.26-1). Some servers may have multiple PHP versions installed, are you using the correct executable?*

My php version : PHP 7.1.6-2 (cli) (built: Jun 14 2017 05:31:31) ( NTS )

Can anyone help me?

Comment: did you install latest php to another location?

Comment: I don't think so. I'm using command " sudo apt-get upgrade " and " sudo apt-get install php7.1 "

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your php7 version looks to be the php-cli version and is not the one used by your http server (apache or other) : display a `phpinfo();` in your browser.

It looks like you are using debian, first remove php5 : `apt-get remove php5* libapache2-mod-php5` and install the 7 version, something like :

```
apt-get install apache2 php7.0 libapache2-mod-php7.0 php7.0-cli php7.0-zip php7.0-intl php7.0-common php7.0-curl php7.0-imagick php7.0-gd php7.0-json php7.0-ldap  php7.0-mcrypt  php7.0-memcache php7.0-memcached php7.0-mysql php7.0-pgsql php7.0-readline php7.0-bcmath php7.0-mbstring php7.0-xml
```

Moodle has no concern with this.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. After upgrading xampp, my problem has solved.